# In displaying multiple icons within a scroll view, is there a quicker way to display the icons rather than using autolayout?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-autolayout

I am creating a sound board app with over 100 sounds. At the moment, I am spacing them all out manually and then contraining them individually to the view using the current canvas value.

I have two issues with this:

1. It is very time consuming and I am sure there must be a quicker way to do it (but I don't want to change it in case I'm wrong and have to start over)
2. The method of constraining to current value does work in portrait mode but does not work in landscape mode

Comment: Maybe I understand wrong: But why you don't use a TableView or a ContainerView?
Create an array with your sound data and read it out. There are tons of tutorials in web/youtube. It's easy to handle and working really good for landscape and portrait

Comment: Do you think it would be easier to do this considering I have spent so much time working on auto layout? Will the table view take much time for this?

Comment: I cant say without seeing code. Show what data you want or need to visualize

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use a grid layout and have a dedicated render function to handle the layout on an orientation update.